# Why the same thread trying to lock the resource?

Tags: java, multithreading

### The main class trying to create 4 threads

After running the threads, each thread tries to lock. And when one thread gets the lock, the rest will wait to unlock.
In my case, once `Thread 0` found that the resource is locked, and then `Thread 0` went in the wait state, then why again `Thread 0` tries to lock the resource.

```java
package com.test.thread;

public class LockImplementation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyNewThread myThread1 = new MyNewThread(1);
        MyNewThread myThread2 = new MyNewThread(2);
        MyNewThread myThread3 = new MyNewThread(3);
        MyNewThread myThread4 = new MyNewThread(3);

        myThread1.start();
        myThread2.start();
        myThread3.start();
        myThread4.start();              
    }               
}

class Lock {

    private boolean isLocked = false;
    private Thread lockingThread = null;
    int count = 0;

    public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        if (isLocked) {
            System.out.println("trying to lock by thread " + 
            lockingThread.getName());
            wait();
        }
        System.out.println("Locked by thread " + 
        Thread.currentThread().getName());
        isLocked = true;
        lockingThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }

    public synchronized void unLock() {
        if (this.lockingThread != Thread.currentThread()) {
            throw new IllegalMonitorStateException("Calling thread has not locked this lock");
        }
        isLocked = false;
        lockingThread = null;
        notify();
    }
}

class MyNewThread extends Thread {

    int thNo;
    private static Lock lock;

    public MyNewThread(int thNo) {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(thNo + "");
        this.thNo = thNo;
        lock = new Lock();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("start running thread no " + 
        Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            lock.lock();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            lock.unLock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("end running thread no " + 
        Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }               
}
```

Why is the same thread trying to lock the resource?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Your program has one static variable, `lock`, but it creates four new `Lock` objects, and assigns the variable four times.  That probably isn't right.

Comment: Your `if` tests should be `while` tests.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when first time you enter lock method you set your locking thread as first that enters it. Next threads when call lock() see that isLocked is true and wait, but locking thread still the same and it doesn't update.